# Where to find Callback URL

Tags: facebook, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I am using webhook to create bot for page. I got everything but not getting where to get Callback URL
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the concept of webhooks. The `Callback URL` is simply the location that you want Facebook to deliver messages to.

For example: if you are running a server at `https://my_awesome_service.com` and you want it to receive facebook updates, you would first create a route (let's say `/v1/facebook_subscriptions`) in your service. Once that's ready, you would insert `https://my_awesome_service.com/v1/facebook_subscriptions` into that Callback URL field. Facebook will then do a `GET` on that URL, which your server must reply to correctly. After that's done, Facebook will start sending you `POST`'s, based on the subscription fields you set up.

There's a lot more information about this in the [Facebook API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks#callback).

Answer (score 2):

Callback URL(s)
A callback URL indicates where the user is to be redirected after a successful sign-in. Choose at least one callback URL, and it should:

Be an absolute URI.

Be pre-registered with a client.

Not include a fragment component.

See OAuth 2.0 - Redirection Endpoint.

Amazon Cognito requires HTTPS over HTTP except for http://localhost for testing purposes only.

App callback URLs such as myapp://example are also supported.